# How do I create a casted type of an object from the returned result of a different object

Tags: java, generics, casting, wildcard

I want to be able to cast a `CompletableFuture<?>` to say a `CompletableFuture<String[]>` if a certain method returns a `String[]`

So I have a `CompletableFuture<?>` from a Queue, and I want to know how to correctly cast it without having to always check for my specific case

This is what I have currently...

```
    CompletableFuture<?> cb = cbQueue.poll();

    switch(subChannel) {
        case "GetServers":
            ((CompletableFuture<String[]>) cb).complete(in.readUTF().split(", "));
            break;
    }
```

But instead I want to be able to just write...

```
    CompletableFuture<?> cb = cbQueue.poll();

    switch(subChannel) {
        case "GetServers":
            complete(cb, in.readUTF().split(", "));
            break;
    }
```

And it would appropriately cast according to the type passed (in this case, String[])
This is because I have a lot of check cases, and am just curious so that I don't have to unnecessarily cast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a helper method... this still has the chance of going wrong at runtime due to unchecked cast

```
  public void stuff() {

    CompletableFuture<?> c = new CompletableFuture<String>();

    complete(c,"bla");

  }

  private static <T> void complete(CompletableFuture<?> c, T value) {
    ((CompletableFuture<T>) c).complete(value);
  }
```

Comment: This is fine solution, but unsafe sadly!

Comment: Im fine with unsafe, Ill just completeExceptionally, cheers for this, so simple I was definitely over complicating it haha

Answer (score 1):

The solution to problems like this is usually a layer of indirection. Either another object should be introduced between the `Queue` and the `CompletableFuture` or between the `CompletableFuture` and the `String[]`.

```
Queue<Sometype> -> Sometype -> CompletableFuture<String[]> -> String[]
```

where there are `Sometype` implementations for different `CompletableFuture` types

or

```
Queue<CompletableFuture<Sometype>> -> CompletableFuture<Sometype> -> Sometype -> String[]
```

where there are `Sometype` implementations for different types, such as `String[]`

Comment: OK, but what if he wants to cast it to something other than String[]? What then?

Comment: @MS90 You have multiple `Sometype` implementations. Some of them may use `String[]` some of them some other type.